# HTML Table Formatting: 2 colspan cell messes up column width

Tags: html, css, html-table

So say I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading:</th><td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading 2:</th><td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Really long heading:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This creates a table with two columns, one for headers (left) and one for values (right) - except for one row, where a long header is taking up both columns, and the value is showed in the right most column on the next row.  Along with this, I have some styling; most importantly:

```
td:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

This makes it so the right most column takes any extra space.  And what I have is working, even though the "really long" header is longer/wider than the header column.  However, when I add a few more words to the really long header (but not making it long enough to increase the width of the whole table), after a certain point the width of the left column starts to increase with the length of the long header, decreasing the width of the right column.  What's going on?

Comment: Can you make an example to explain it? I made a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/druqcg3t/ (also added borders so to see it clearly)

Comment: Aha, I replicated what I am seeing after adding "white-space:nowrap" to the headers.  Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/s60twrrL/

Change the length of the long heading to see it affecting the column width

Comment: Thanks, and I added a possible answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define width:100% of an cell of a table with multiple column.
You should use colgroup tag to define width of cell:

```css
.col-left {
  width: 20%;
}
.col-right {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-left">
    <col class="col-right">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Heading:</th><td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Really long heading:</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>lorem  ispum dolores hello</th><td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another tricks to set a cell at the minimum and obviously the another cell take the rest of the width, are to set the first one at 1px:

```css
table {
    width: 200px;
}
th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
th {
    width:1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>hello</th>
        <td>world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Setting the last column's width to 100% is the standard way I've heard of making the last column take any extra space (and making all the other columns of minimal width for their content).  Setting the columns each to an explicit width is not the same.  Also, as I said before, setting the last column's width to 100% works for me in most situations, except for this specific one

Comment: Ah, setting the left column's width to 1px instead does seem to work - it will only work for 2 columns, but in this case that's all I have.  I don't understand why, but that does work.  Thank you